# Unable to create round shape button in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I want to create round shape button for my app which is build upon react native. I had tried the code below but both of them didn't work out for me.

Code snippet 1: `<Button title="+" rounded="true"/>`

Code snippet 2: `addButton: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 40
  }`

Comment: react-native button doesn't have style prop. So you have to create a custom button using such as ```TouchableOpacity```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to style up Views and Touchables to look like the button you want. Here's an example of a circular button component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default ({ title, onPress }) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
  }
})
```